# Liferay jsonws api: how do I get p_auth from a client?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to develop a javascript mobile app that will use a liferay portal jsonws api. I have a username and password. If I try a request using curl with basic auth I can access the resources, but I don't get a token in return, I get a cookie with a sessionid and I have to include username and password in every request. I've no control on the portal. How do I get the p_auth token?

Comment: Did you try with this: Liferay.authToken. It's located in one of liferay's js file Check out liferay source.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have no access to the portal itself; someone else developed the json api using liferay 6.2 and I have no control on anything. I thought I would have a login endpoint but so far it seems it's not the case. Does Liferay as a js library that can be used in external application? From the documentation it is really unclear and the people in charge of the portal aren't really sharing much, the just gave me a user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Liferay.authToken` to get `p_auth` from client.

You may go to browser console and type `Liferay.authToken` to verify that the object is available.

[image: as checked on Liferay.com site]

I've used the same object for auth purpose where I was listing down results from JSONW service call. You can save the value in a variable and set anywhere per requirements. I found this the easiest way:

```
var pAuth = Liferay.authToken;
console.log(pAuth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Becareful, the parameter p_auth is used to prevent CSRF attack. You can obtain the value with this code:

```
String pAuth = com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AuthTokenUtil.getToken(request);
```

TokenUtil is a part of the liferay core, so you must create a hook because the jsp must be in liferay directory, not in a plugin or a portlet because in other classpath you dont have acces to this object.

Comment: If `p_auth` is to prevent CSRF then why it is available as an open access through `Liferay.authToken` object in browser console?

Comment: Liferay.authToken is updated in every request to the portal. The next request needs to pass the last token returned by the portal otherwise this request will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the authentication token (p_auth) by using `Liferay.authToken` predefined variable.